# "TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined". What is the meaning of this in agenda.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2015

This is the stack trace: This happens when I run the server.js file in my project. Also I couldn't find any explanation on the web. Can someone help with this error please?

```
E:\users\ashane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShowTracker\ShowTracker\node_modules\agenda\lib\agenda.js:341
  if ( this._mdb.s.topology.connections().length === 0 ) {                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined
    at Agenda._findAndLockNextJob (E:\users\ashane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShowTracker\ShowTracker\node_modules\agenda\lib\agenda.js:341:17) at jobQueueFilling (E:\users\ashane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShowTracker\ShowTracker\node_modules\agenda\lib\agenda.js:420:10) at processJobs (E:\users\ashane\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShowTracker\ShowTracker\node_modules\agenda\lib\agenda.js:404:7)

    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

These are the only codes that are using angenda and "s" < as a string

```
var mongoConnectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/agenda";
var agenda = require('agenda')({ db: { address: mongoConnectionString } });
var sugar = require('sugar');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// define an agenda job called send email alert.

agenda.define('send email alert', function (job, done) {
    // what should happen when send email alert job is dispatched. 
    // When this job runs, name of the show will be passed in as an optional data object. 
    // Since we are not storing the entire user document in subscribers array (only references), 
    // we have to use Mongoose’s populate method.
    Show.findOne({ name: job.attrs.data }).populate('subscribers').exec(function (err, show) {
        var emails = show.subscribers.map(function (user) {
            return user.email;
        });

        var upcomingEpisode = show.episodes.filter(function (episode) {
            return new Date(episode.firstAired) > new Date();
        })[0];

        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
            service: 'SendGrid',
            auth: { user: 'hslogin', pass: 'hspassword00' }
        });

        // standard Nodemailer boilerplate for sending emails.
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'Fred Foo ✔ <foo@blurdybloop.com>',
            to: emails.join(','),
            subject: show.name + ' is starting soon!',
            text: show.name + ' starts in less than 2 hours on ' + show.network + '.\n\n' +
        'Episode ' + upcomingEpisode.episodeNumber + ' Overview\n\n' + upcomingEpisode.overview
        };

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + response.message);
            smtpTransport.close();
            done();
        });
    });
});

agenda.start();

agenda.on('start', function (job) {
    console.log("Job %s starting", job.attrs.name);
});

agenda.on('complete', function (job) {
    console.log("Job %s finished", job.attrs.name);
});
```

Comment: That means the code is trying to access the property `s` of an object variable that is not defined. If you want more help, show us the code where this happens. Is the source file something you wrote, or a dependency you're using?

Comment: @Antoine These are the codes only use the agenda node modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In agenda.js,  at line `if ( this._mdb.s.topology.connections().length === 0 )`, `this._mdb` is undefined.

The method `Agent.prototype.database` assigns to `_mdb` the returned `db` object from `MongoClient.connect`. So my guess is that the connect operation fails. Are you sure of your connection string?

Comment: Ok I have chaged the connection string to 'localhost:27017/test' still gives me an error. The mongodb says listening to port 27017

Comment: Mongo connection strings must be in the form `mongo://[server]:[port]/[dbname]`. the part after the host/port is the name of the database to connect to. Make sure it's correctl written, and check the permissions too.

Comment: OK it still gives me an error the hosts that are tried are: `localhost:27017/test, 127.0.0.1:27017/test, localhost:52332/test` <-- when the mogos shell started. Still gives me an error.

Comment: Using the same connection string, can you connect to the db with the shell or a gui tool like robomongo?

Comment: How do you connect with Mongo.exe shell??

Comment: Mongo shell does not exactly use the connection string, but you can see this: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. Thank you.

Comment: with the help of the above link I connected with a small example. That worked but with connecting agenda into it the above error throws. Why is that?

Answer (score 7):

it works when .on('ready') function is present. Here is my example.

```
var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: 'localhost:27017/servicebox-dev'}}); 
matcher.matchProviders(agenda);
agenda.on('ready', function() {
    agenda.every('5 seconds', 'match providers'); 
    agenda.start();
});
```

Comment: This fixed my issue too. Interesting how there are so many example which don't use .on()

Comment: The accepted answer isn't very helpful.  I think most people know to use a working connection string.  This answer, however, solved my problem.